# How do we show Google Maps in Tizen Wearable Devices

Tags: javascript, google-maps, tizen

I am trying to show Google Maps on my `Gear S3 Frontier, Tizen 4.0`. I'm getting the following output:

[image]

I want the all these buttons (e.g. Satellite, Zoom-in and Zoom-out etc.) to be fit on the screen.

Here's my code so far:

```
 function initMap() {
    var currPosition = {
        lat: 33.6169854124275,
        lng: 73.0656100279796
    };
    var mapProperties = {
        // Start position
        center: currPosition,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapProperties);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: currPosition,
        map: myMap
    });        
}
```

Web Search showed my many ways to draw circles and polygons etc. but I couldn't find **any way to fit the map to a circular screen**

Comment: According to the [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms-20180207#8.-licenses-from-google-to-you.) - *8.5 Proprietary Rights Notices. You will not remove, obscure, or alter any proprietary rights notices (including copyright and trademark notices, Terms of Use links, or Brand Features) displayed or provided through the Service.* - Your implementation obscures all the proprietary rights notices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can remove them with [`disableDefaultUI:true`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.disableDefaultUI) in the [`MapOptions`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions)

```
var mapProperties = {
    // Start position
    center: currPosition,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI:true
};

var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapProperties);
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var currPosition = {
    lat: 33.6169854124275,
    lng: 73.0656100279796
  };
  var mapProperties = {
    // Start position
    center: currPosition,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  };

  var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapProperties);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: currPosition,
    map: myMap
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapCanvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```